# Why do French power sockets have a protruding ground?

Tags: power, connector, ground, socket

French power sockets have a protruding ground. Why did they make this decision?

I can't see any major benefits from it, it saves some pennies on each power cord, but it exposes the ground connection to people nearby, which can be dangerous as in real life grounds are not perfect, they can have a live voltage and are a risk of electric shock if there's lightning nearby.

Once someone told me they are safer because the ground connects first, but this is also nonsense as the order of connection depends on the size of the plugs alone and not where they are.

In case you don't know what I am talking about:

[image: French power outlet]

Comment: It does ensure the ground connects before anything else does. "*Once someone told me they are safer because the ground connects first, but this is also nonsense as the order of connection depends on the size of the plugs alone and not where they are.*" I don't understand what you are trying to say here. I don't see why size of plugs or where they are has anything to do with anything.

Comment: How? You don't need to put the plug on the outlet in order to ensue this, just make the ground pin longer on the power cord.

Comment: Perhaps they could not make the ground pin any longer due to risk of mechanical damage, but they could not make the hot and neutral pins any shorter because then they would be hazardously close to the front of the socket

Comment: It is a design that works, the UK has an earth pin that is longer than the other two pins and that also works. Each country thinks its own design is best, or the design of the country they are asdociated with...

Comment: Also, ground connections are already exposed just from the screws holding outlet faces to the wall (well, if France is anything like North America). So if they are mis-wired, it's not like concealing the ground prong is protecting anyone.

Comment: There are similar sockets in other countries, and the ground is often easily touched in many other countries (for example the cover plate mounting screws in the US/Canada, or the side ground clips in some Euro receptacles). There is something similar in Russia but with a smaller pin size. Allegedly a bit incompatible to slow down invaders. It's just another way of doing it. It is unsafe in the sense that a cord with a ground can be plugged into a socket without one  if compatible ungrounded sockets exist. That's not possible with a protruding ground.

Comment: Perhaps it's so that idiots who [connect ground to hot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse+polarity+bootleg+ground) get immediate feedback?

Comment: By the way, the French AC power connectors are the only example of a hermaphrodite  AC power connector. All others standard AC power connectors are either male or female.

Comment: _"... but it exposes the ground connection to people nearby ..."_ - If you connect any grounded device (PC, washing machine, etc) to the socket, then any metal part of that device exposes the ground connection to people nearby. That's pretty much the point of a ground connection. I don't think the ground pin is a big deal in comparison.

Answer (score 4):

This design **forces** the user to only plug compatible equipment in that socket. That is, if you get a German-only plug (where ground contacts are elsewhere), you simply won't be able to insert it in the French socket, as there will be no hole to receive the ground pin. If the plug fits, you can be quite certain that the appliance is correctly grounded. Indeed, this doesn't apply to flat plugs which have no ground pin, but appliances having such plugs don't require grounding in the first place.

In the opposite case (French-only plug, German socket) the plug will mechanically fit, but the ground will not be connected, giving a misleading impression of safety.

When the ground contact goes live, no plug design will make it safe: no matter how concealed the ground pin is, you will get a shock the moment you try to operate the equipment you have plugged in.

BTW, I don't see how this design "saves some pennies on each power cord", because you still need to make a female receptacle for the ground pin, which I suspect cost more than a third pin would have.

Comment: "in the opposite case (French-only plug, German socket) the plug will mechanically fit" no it won't. The german plug (and the hybrid german/french plug) has notches that the french plug does not and the socket cavity is shaped to require these notches.

Comment: This logic applies to almost all sockets, you can't fit an American power cord on a British outlet for example, and neither have a ground protruding.

Comment: What I meant about saving money is that it's cheaper to make a metallic ring to connect the ground plug, than a plug, as it takes a lot more metal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that the reason for the unusual earthing arrangements on french and german plugs is backwards compatibility with existing installations.

Appliances can be categorised into 3 categories.

- Class 0: no earth connection, not "single fault safe" (now banned in most first-world countries)
- Class 1: "single fault safe" only if an earth connection is present.
- Class 2: no earth connection, "single fault safe"

If your existing installed base of installations has no earth provision and your existing base of appliances is class 0 then it can be argued that it is sensible to let people plug class 1 appliances into their existing unearthed sockets. They aren't any less safe than the old class 0 appliances were.

There is also an argument to be made that having some appliances earthed while there are class 0 appliances in use makes things less safe than having no earthing at all.

Adding a conventional earth pin disallows plugging new appliances into existing installations, and does nothing to prevent old class 0 appliances from being brought into new earthed installations.

The design of the German and French plugs on the other hand allows new appliances to be used in existing installations in a way that is no less safe than before, while keeping old class 0 appliances out of new installations.

Answer (score 1):

> Once someone told me they are safer because the ground connects first,
>   but this is also nonsense as **the order of connection depends on the
>   size of the plugs alone and not where they are**

You are right. The ground pin could be on the cord itself. But it is how it is. But this is a generic argument, looking at may available type sockets and plugs used worldwide (Type A to Type N).

Until there is one universal plug and socket adaption say by the year 2200 (Like phone charger pin types reduced to two now, majorly from many.  ), the variants are going to stay.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#CEE_7/5_socket_and_CEE_7/6_plug_(French;_Type_E)

> Plug Type E
>
> Used in: France, Belgium, Slovakia and Tunisia among others (see
>   complete list of countries on the right)
>
> The Type E electrical plug has two 4.8 mm round pins spaced 19 mm
>   apart and a hole for the socket's male earthing pin. The Type E plug
>   has a rounded shape and the Type E socket has a round recess. Type E
>   plugs are rated 16 amps.
>
> Note: The CEE 7/7 plug was developed to work with Type E and Type F
>   sockets with a female contact (to accept the earthing pin of the Type
>   E socket) and has earthing clips on both sides (to work with Type F
>   sockets).

https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeE.htm

Comment: Do you think the politicians could get together and agree a “common” plug ? :)

Comment: Yes..by 2200 for sure

Comment: Won’t happen, probably because some or all the countries won’t exist by then...

Comment: @SolarMike that's the catch.. probably at that point in time it will easy to settle to one or none :P

Comment: Just saying, France also invented metric time...compatibility hasn't always been their primary consideration.  https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/32127/decimal-time-how-french-made-10-hour-day

Comment: Some politicians just don't want to agree to make it harder to import devices from other countries, trying to stimulate local manufactures (which by now its known by economists that this doesn't work at all, but politicians aren't economists, they are just good at saying whatever gets them elected)

Answer (score 0):

Without the original argumentation how the design was presented to be the one and only right version we can only guess.

**My guess:** It's difficult to modify existing non-grounded non-double-insulated device plugs to fit. Grounding at the edges of the plug need only a little material removal with a saw or knife or by melting. This type of grounding needs a hole which requires more complex tools and there can be metal inside the plug in front of the drill.

Answer (score 0):

"it exposes the ground connection to people nearby, which can be dangerous as in real life grounds are not perfect, "

In fact the opposite is true. The purpose of the ground is to give a path for the current from a faulty device  that is not through the body of the user . In other words the current is *from* whatever is plugged in *to* the socket. Thus the French design guarantees that you can't get shocked by accidentally touching a "live" ground line.

Of course,  in order to get shocked on the ground line on a plug from somewhere that has an exposed ground on the plug rather than socket, you would have to touch it while plugging it in, which you can argue to be highly unlikely. Thus making the whole point moot.

But anyway, as i said, the French design guarantees you wont manage to zap yourself that way.

Comment: "*...  the current is from whatever is plugged in to the socket.*" No, in the case of a serious earth fault on another appliance the earth voltage will rise - theoretically up to half the live voltage if the conductors are the same size. That means that all protruding earth pins could be hazardous. "*... you would have to touch it while plugging it in, which you can argue to be highly unlikely.*" Those sockets accept the flat 2-pin plugs used on double-insulated appliances. It is very likely that you would touch the protruding earth pin when inserting one of those plugs.

Comment: Think about a lightning strike near that power socket, or another appliance on the same ground, malfunctioning, and discharging on the ground wire....and you, right near there.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the CEE 7/5 outlet a hermaphrodite? It's to ensure safety when dealing with all the various types of CEE plugs.
It accepts the CEE7/16 and CEE 7/17 for products that don't need a ground. It accepts the CEE 7/6 and CEE 7/7 that do include a ground socket. Unfortunately, it prevents insertion of the CEE 7/2 with does not need a ground, but that plug is now obsolete. Had the ground been a socket instead of a pin, it would have not been able to prevent the insertion of the CEE 7/4 plug, which does require a ground and would have been unsafe. So, that's why the ground is a pin. Of course, the other contacts are sockets to avoid shocking people. Having a male ground pin plus two female line sockets makes this outlet a hermaphrodite.

[image: Compatibility of CEE outlets and inlets]